# Need image to match the size of a flexible parent wrapper

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to create an image gallery that stays centered on the page and has a max height/width of 85% of the browser window. Here are the goals:

- Absolutely no Javascript (and no we don't want a 3rd party solution)
- image should always be exactly the same size as the wrapper (except padding/border/margin)
- image should never go beyond the 85% max width/height set on the wrapper

The issue is that when I have a very tall (or wide) image, the img will ignore the parents max-height and run outside its wrapper .

- Overflow doesn't seem to work (we don't want scroll bars).
- Setting the img height/width to 100% doesn't seem to work and I'm assuming this is because its parent is absolute positioned?
- Can't set height/width (only max) of the wrapper div because if the image is smaller there will be a bunch of white space. Again, we want to do this without JavaScript.

Sorry in advance for the inline styles.

```
<div id='wrap' style='position: absolute; top: XXXpx; left: XXXpx; max-width: 85%; max-height: 85%'>
    <img src='mypic.jpg'>
    <div id='leftArrow' style='position: absolute...'></div>
    <div id='rightArrow' style='position: absolute...'></div>
    <div id='thumbnails' style='position: absolute...'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Crucial: what kind of browser support do you need?

Comment: Correct if I'm wrong here but I'm assuming background-size: contain would require you to set the height/width on the wrapper div. You'd have white space on the shorter of the width/height since the images will change dimensions based on what the client uploads.

Comment: We'd like to support all the way down to IE8, but IE9+ might have to be sufficient.

Comment: IE8 support would almost necessarily require some JavaScript, if only to provide a shim for newer browser features.  IE9 does support `transform` properties, however.

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this:

## [Fiddled up for ya](http://jsfiddle.net/nu7rk9b8/)

So we're basically foregoing the need to set a height on the wrapper at all.  If there's no height defined on an element, percentage is based off the lowest element with defined width in the DOM hierarchy which is a parent of the element receiving percentage.

So in this case, the `max-width: 85%` and `max-height: 85%` refers to the `body` element as its the nearest parent with a defined size.

**HTML**

```
<div id='wrap'>
    <img src='https://placehold.it/1200x1400' />
    <div id='leftArrow' style='position: absolute'></div>
    <div id='rightArrow' style='position: absolute'></div>
    <div id='thumbnails' style='position: absolute'></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

#wrap {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 50%; 
    left: 50%; 
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
#wrap img {
    max-height: 85%;
    max-width: 85%;
}
```

Part of the beauty of this solution is that we're basically telling the wrapper element to shove itself to the center of the page, and then using the CSS 3 `transform` property to dynamically slide itself to the center of the page by offsetting it relative to its own `height`/`width` (that's what the `translate(-50%, -50%)` property is doing).

That means that no matter what size the image is, it will render consistently at the center of the page.  If you fill out those `leftArrow`, `rightArrow` and `thumbnails` sections, the `#wrap` element will still render at the exact center of the page.  `transform` is one of the most useful features introduced in the CSS 3 spec for this and many more reasons.

## Edit:

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nu7rk9b8/1/)**

So the difference here is that since we need such a tight wrap on the `.wrap` element, we're going to use some of the lesser-known units of measure to set picture height.

Check this altered CSS:

```
#wrap {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 50%; 
    left: 50%; 
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: #075883;
    max-height: 85%;
    max-width: 85%;
}
#wrap img {
    max-height: 100%!important;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

**Important things to note here**

1. We move the `max-width` and `max-height` rules to the wrapper.  This ensures that it scales appropriately.
2. The change to the `max-width` and `max-height` rules mean that we need to constrain the picture in a different means.  You'd think we could just use a `max-width: 100%` or `max-height: 100%` to do so, but you can't.  `max-height` doesn't work in this situation, and the picture bleeds its bounds horrendously.  But no worries, as we have *viewport relative* sizing that we can fall back on.  We set the `max-width` to `85vw` (85/100 view-widths) and the `max-height` to `85vh` (85/100 view-heights).

That should do it.

Comment: That centering trick is very cool, but the image height/width is different than the wrapper div. Put a background-color on the #wrap and you can see what I mean. Also, the scaling is only working in one direction?